# Django form not getting value for clean method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I'm trying to write a clean method form one of my forms in Django 3.0.Here when the user selects the production_process the clean method is not getting any value.And rising an error in my template page as `Production process: Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`

Here is my forms.py

```
class ProductionCapacityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(required=True, widget=forms.DateInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker'
                                }))
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.client = kwargs.pop('client')
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        try:
            self.work_time = kwargs.pop('work_time')
        except:
            pass
        super(ProductionCapacityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['production_process'].queryset = ProductionProcess.objects.filter(is_deleted=False).values_list("name", flat=True).distinct()
        
        self.fields['date'].widget.attrs\
            .update({
                'placeholder': 'Select Date',
                'class': 'input-class_name'
            })
    def clean(self):
       production_process = self.cleaned_data.get('production_process')
       number_of_people = self.cleaned_data.get('number_of_people')
       datee = self.cleaned_data.get('date')
       pk = self.instance.pk
       if production_process:
         try:
           if production_process not in ProductionCapacity.objects.get(client=self.client, date=datee,production_process=production_process.id):
                self.cleaned_data['production_process'] = get_object_or_404(ProductionProcess,client=self.client,id=production_process.id)
        except:
            if ProductionCapacity.objects.filter(client=self.client, date=datee, production_process=production_process.id).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError('Production Process is already exists')
        
        self.cleaned_data['number_of_people'] = number_of_people
        self.cleaned_data['date'] = datee
    return super(ProductionCapacityForm, self).clean()
class Meta:
    model = ProductionCapacity
    widgets = {
        "date": McamDateInput1,
    }
    fields = ['date', 'production_process', 'number_of_people']
```

Here is my models.py

```
class ProductionCapacity(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    production_process = models.ForeignKey(ProductionProcess,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    number_of_people = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is my template.html

```
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
<fieldset class="add">
    {% if form.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-block alert-error">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong class="alert-heading">Oops!</strong>
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <ul>
            {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.errors %}
            <li>
                <strong>{{ field.label }}:</strong> {{ field.errors|join:" " }}
            </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <fieldset>
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label pull-left" for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {{ field }}
             
            <p>{{ field.help_text }}</p>
            </div> <!--/controls-->
           
        </div> <!--/control-group-->
        {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

Plese help out to solve this issue

Comment: Can you share your HTML also?

Comment: @SunderamDubey please have a look i have shared by template also

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because of the line:

```
self.cleaned_data['production_process'] = get_object_or_404(ProductionProcess,client=self.client,id=production_process.id)
```

`get_object_or_404` is used when you're retrieving an object to display. In this case you're retrieving it in code only. You don't want a 404 http response, which almost certainly is not a valid production process.

Just get the object, and you'll get `None` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Firstly the code is not entering into the if condition(i.e if production_process: ).It is giving None for production_process = self.cleaned_data.get('production_process')

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I misunderstood what you were saying there. THe other answer given here by @Sunderam Dubey should then solve your problem ...

Answer (score 0):

I made a small modification to the `clean()` method to fix the issue you are experiencing with the `production_proces` field not being included in the form's `cleaned_data` dictionary.

Try this:

```py
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    production_process = cleaned_data.get('production_process')
    number_of_people = cleaned_data.get('number_of_people')
    datee = cleaned_data.get('date')
    pk = self.instance.pk
    if production_process:
        try:
            if production_process.id not in ProductionCapacity.objects.filter(client=self.client, date=datee, production_process=production_process).values_list('production_process__id', flat=True):
                cleaned_data['production_process'] = get_object_or_404(ProductionProcess, client=self.client, id=production_process.id)
        except:
            if ProductionCapacity.objects.filter(client=self.client, date=datee, production_process=production_process).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError('Production Process is already exists')

    cleaned_data['number_of_people'] = number_of_people
    cleaned_data['date'] = datee

    return cleaned_data
```

The main change here is that I'm now calling `super().clean()` to get the form's `cleaned_data` dictionary, instead of returning it directly. Then I'm updating this dictionary with the cleaned values for `number_of_people` and `datee`. Finally, I'm returning the updated `cleaned_data` dictionary. This ensures that all cleaned fields are included in the `cleaned_data` dictionary, including `production_process`.

Comment: Even in this way also i am getting the error that Production Process is not a valid choice..it is giving None for this line production_process = cleaned_data.get('production_process') still

Comment: I'm not following this method.  `production_process = cleaned_data.get('production_process'` does not return data for me, so how can I use it in the if statement?   If I add fields in the `__init__` method, I can't seem to get them to show up in the clean/cleaned_data/responses.  What am I missing?